# Can entity framework database-first successfully build models from any SQLServer db?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, ef-database-first

I'm considering using entity framework database-first approach. The database in question uses various non-standard techniques, eg 'informal' foreign keys. I'd like to confirm that it's still possible to create a usable EF model from this database, even if all the relationships are not recognised?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this.  Generate the model from the database as normal, then modify the generated entities in order to introduce the relationships.  You'll need to set a Null database initializer to tell EF it should not try and update the database to match its model:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new NullDatabaseInitializer<MyContext>());
```

There's no requirement for foreign keys to exist in the database to match your model - as long as the navigation properties have been added on the entities, EF will generate the correct SQL queries accordingly.

I would recommend the use of the `[ForeignKey]` attribute to clarify the names of your foreign key fields for when they don't conform to EF's expected patterns (or you could modify the Conventions accordingly).  For example...

```
public class Child {
    // ...

    public int Parent_ID { get; set; }     // <-- non-standard name

    // Add these to introduce the navigation property without a formal relationship
    [ForeignKey("Parent_ID")]
    public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

I have used this approach on a MySQL database with no foreign keys at all.

Comment: Thankyou. Having looked into this a little more now, can you clarify, are you referring to generating a code-first model, or an edmx?

Comment: Generate an EDMX and then modify the partial classes it produces